# Get source branch name in commit-msg hook of merge commit

Tags: git

In the commit-msg hook for a merge commit, how can I get the branch name of the immediate source branch for the merge?  I can get the target branch with something like

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

But HEAD and HEAD^ both refer to the target branch.  Is there a way to programmatically determine the source?  I'm using a bash script for the hook.

The default merge commit message contains this text:

> Merge branch 'source-branch' into target-branch

So the commit-msg hook could grab the name right out of the message, but there's no guarantee that the user hasn't edited it.  If there's a more foolproof method, I would prefer it.

Edit: ah, unfortunately I also didn't realize that commit-msg doesn't actually even run on merge commits!  So I'll have to find a different way to do what I want anyway.

Comment: I am not sure when git deletes `MERGE_HEAD` reference. Test it if it is available to your hook when your do a merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the commit being merged:

```
git rev-parse MERGE_HEAD
```

I do not think that there is a way to find the branch name other than guessing with a command like:

```
git for-each-ref | grep ^$(git rev-parse MERGE_HEAD)
```

(which finds all branches pointing to the commit you are merging)

Note that the commit being merged does not *have to* be a branch, one can also merge a commit directly like `git merge deadbeef`.

In the case of octopus merge, there is more than one commit being merged at the same time, and `MERGE_HEAD` is not present.

If you are to extract it from the merge message, then using `.git/MERGE_MSG` is safer than `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`, since it is less likely to be hand-edited.

The message is generated by `git merge`, hence has access to the branch name from `git merge`'s arguments, but this does not seem to be stored on disk.

Comment: Thanks, MERGE_HEAD is pretty much the answer to my question, but good point that theoretically it could belong to multiple branches.

Comment: I get the error "fatal: ambiguous argument 'MERGE_HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

Answer (score 1):

> but there's no guarantee that the user hasn't edited it

imvho you *should* use the merge commit summary line, after the user has had a chance to edit it.

I've edited subject lines for good reason.  All branch names are repo-local. Sometimes you're pulling from a coworker, sometimes you realize you typo'd during branch creation, or you're publishing from a wip that turned out well, there's lots more ways to get there.

If you're worried about inbound commits not meeting your standards for one of your own repositories, vet the inbound commits in its pre-receive.  No dvcs can be sure without doing that anyway.

```
#!/bin/sh
rc=0
existing=$(git for-each-ref --format='%(object)' refs/heads refs/tags);
validmergesubject='Merge (branch|tag) '\''[^ ]*'\'' (of|into) .*'
while read old new ref; do
    while read commit Subject; do
        if [[ ! $Subject =~ $validmergesubject ]]; then
            echo Merge $commit in $ref history has invalid summary line \"$Subject\"
            rc=1;
        fi;
    done  >&2 <<EOD
$(git log --merges --pretty='%H %s' $new --not $existing)
EOD
done
exit $rc
```

Comment: This is also a good point, that the user may want to alter the name.  In our particular case it's not necessarily an issue, because we're only using the branch name to fill into a macro that the user enters into the commit message anyway, so they could simply change what they enter there instead, but good point regardless.